# SQL Return Count of Answers with 0's for Choices from another table

Tags: sql, join

Here is what I want I want my result to look like:

**EDIT!** More useful structure provided [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/need-to-join-count-and-group-across-five-tables)

```
 Answer  Counts
 ------  -------
 0       0
 1       12
 2       4
 3       0
 4       3
 5       6
```

Responses are stored as 1,2,3,4,5 Where each N = A,B,C,D or something like that.

My problem is

```
SELECT COUNT(answer_sequence) AS 'Answer Count'
FROM tblILDSlideResponses
WHERE response_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tblILDSlideResponseInfo
    WHERE (slide_id = @slide) AND (session_id = @sessionid)
)
GROUP BY answer_sequence
```

Returns Something like this:

```
 Answer  Counts
 ------  -------
 0       12
 1       4
 2       3
 3       6
```

So when there is a possible choice with no answers I get no count.
So I know I need to grab the possible choices which are available here:

```
SELECT Choice AS 'Choices'
FROM tblSurveyAnswerChoices
WHERE QID IN (
    SELECT question_id
    FROM tblILDSlide
    WHERE id = @slide
)
```

and then somehow map them to the answers. But how would I accomplish this and still keep these in order. I am thinking I need to return a blank row for every answer that exists in the tblSurveyAnswerChoices then somehow join the other counts to that, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT!**

In response to the request from @Christopherous5000:

```
dbo.tblSLideResponseInfo
id (PK,int,not null)
user_id (nvarchar(50), not null) --will be FK eventualy
slide_id (FK,int, not null)
response_date (datetime, not null)
session_id (FK,int,not null)

dbo.tblSLideResponses --can store multiple answer for same response
response_id (FK,int,not null)
answer_sequence(int, null)
pther (nvarchar(50), null)
```

Comment: Please add the table structure for tblILDSlideResponses and tblILDSlideResponseInfo

Comment: @Christopherous5000 he updated the question btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post already includes a good answer:  "I am thinking I need to return a blank row for every answer that exists in the tblSurveyAnswerChoices then somehow join the other counts to that."

Here is one way to do so:

```
select choice, ifnull(countanswervalue,0) 
from tblsurveyanswerchoice
left join 
    (select answer_sequence, count(answer_sequence) as countanswervalue
    from tblslideresponses
    group by answer_sequence) 
    as countanswer on countanswer.answer_sequence=tblsurveyanswerchoice.sequence
/* the where clause is what you already posted */
where qid in (select question_id from tblidslide where id = @slide)
```

The use of `left join` ensures that any choice in the first table will be listed.  By default, left join would return NULL for items not existing in the second table, but `ifnull` lets you replace NULL with 0.

NOTE: `ifnull` in MySQL should be replaced by `isnull` in TSQL

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(answer_sequence) AS 'Answer Count'
> FROM tblILDSlideResponses
> WHERE response_id IN (
>       SELECT id FROM tblILDSlideResponseInfo
>       WHERE (slide_id = @slide) AND (session_id = @sessionid)
>       )
> GROUP BY answer_sequence
> ```
>
> (...) So when there is a possible choice with no answers I get no count. So I know I need to grab the possible choices which are available here.

Or, you could try using a [left join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```
 SELECT answer_sequence, COUNT(answer_sequence) AS 'Answer Count'
 FROM tblILDSlideResponses
 LEFT JOIN tblILDSlideResponseInfo
 ON (slide_id = @slide) AND (session_id = @sessionid)
 AND tblILDSlideResponseInfo.id = tblILDSlideResponses.response_id
 GROUP BY answer_sequence
```

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid"? If you do only a count it returns the total number of answers received. Combining the count and group by gives a count of the individual answers, which is what I need.  Your suggestion above only returns the same response as before. It doesn't add a zero for every available answer in tblSurveyAnswerChoices.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to edit that out. It actually does make sense -- it's basically behaving as if it were count(1) or count(*).